# Rectangles with monochromatic corners in a $7\times7$ grid

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, coloring

We are going to color all $1\times 1$ squares inside the $7\times7$ square in black or white. Among the rectangles formed by $1\times 1$ squares, the number of rectangles whose four corner squares have been colored by same color is at least $21$.

I want to prove this theorem and I know that it uses double counting, but I can't think further.

Comment: Are you colouring $49$ squares or $49$ vertices or $64$ vertices or something else?

Comment: What is the size of rectangles you are speaking about ? $2 \times 1$ or any size ?

Comment: 49 squaresAny size

Comment: Please specify, are you colouring $1\times1$ squares or vertices? The first sentence says squares, the second sentence assumes vertices. As it stands the question makes no sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each row, write down all the monochromatic pairs of cells in that row. For example, for the row $$\blacksquare \square \square \blacksquare \blacksquare \blacksquare \square$$ numbering the cells $1$ through $7$ from left to right, we would write down "$2$ and $3$ are white", "$2$ and $7$ are white", $3$ and $7$ are white", "$1$ and $4$ are black", "$1$ and $5$ are black", "$1$ and $6$ are black", "$4$ and $5$ are black", "$4$ and $6$ are black", and "$5$ and $6$ are black".

There are $2 \binom 72 = 42$ possible pairs we could write down. In a row with $x$ white squares and $7-x$ black squares, we write down $\binom x2 + \binom{7-x}{2}$ pairs, which is at least $\binom32 + \binom42 = 9$. So with $7$ rows, we write down at least $63$ pairs.

If we write down $63$ pairs, and there's only $42$ distinct options, then at least $63-42 = 21$ times, we write down a pair that we've written down for a previous row. Each time we do that, we get a rectangle whose four corners are all the same color.

(For example, if we write down "$3$ and $7$ are white" for row $2$ and again for row $5$, that means that the cells $(2,3)$, $(2,7)$, $(5,3)$, and $(5,7)$ are all white, and these are the corners of a $4 \times 5$ rectangle.)

Exactly $21$ pairs is possible. Here is an example:

\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\blacksquare & \blacksquare & \blacksquare &      \square &     \square &     \square &     \square \\
\blacksquare &      \square &     \square &\blacksquare & \blacksquare &      \square &     \square \\
\blacksquare &      \square &     \square &     \square &     \square &\blacksquare & \blacksquare  \\
     \square &\blacksquare &      \square &\blacksquare &      \square &\blacksquare &      \square \\
     \square &\blacksquare &      \square &     \square &\blacksquare &      \square &\blacksquare \\
     \square &     \square &\blacksquare & \blacksquare &      \square &     \square &\blacksquare \\
     \square &     \square &\blacksquare &      \square &\blacksquare & \blacksquare &      \square 
\end{array}